# Anyway to fix it the code so that my photo entries are not round like my sidebar

Tags: html, css, themes, tumblr

for some reason I was able to add a code where my sidebar image has around spinning border and it works, but now on Tumblr my photo post are small and round like the sidebar image - I tried to go to the code and see if any code was linked together to make the post resize like the sidebar but found nothing

```
/*   ------   text styles   ------   */



body { background:{color:background}; margin:0px; font-weight:500; color:{color:text}; font-family:'ABeeZee', sans-serif; font-size:10px; line-height:16px; letter-spacing:.5px; text-align:justify; background-image:url('{image:Background}'); }

a { text-decoration:none; color:{color:links}; -moz-transition-duration:1s; -webkit-transition-duration:1s; -o-transition-duration:1s; }

a:hover { color:{color:text}; background:transparent; -moz-transition-duration:1s; -webkit-transition-duration:1s; -o-transition-duration:1s; }

b, strong { color:{color:bold}; font-weight:700; }

em, i { color:{color:italic}; font-weight:600; }

i:hover { background:transparent; }

strike { color:{color:italic}; }

small { font-size:10px; }

big { color:{color:title}; font-weight:600; font-variant:small-caps; letter-spacing:2px; }

sup { text-transform:normal; color:{color:text}; font-size:10px; }

sub { text-transform:normal; color:{color:text}; font-size:10px; }

blockquote { margin-left:5px; padding-left:10px; width:245px; border-left:1px solid {color:background}; }

blockquote blockquote { padding-left:10px; width:230px; border-left:1px solid {color:background}; }

h1 { color:{color:bold}; font-size:8px; letter-spacing:2px; text-transform:uppercase;font-family:'ABeeZee', sans-serif; font-style:none; line-height:10px; text-align:left; padding:0px; }

h2 { text-align: center; font-size:11px; letter-spacing:.5px; text-transform:lowercase; font-style:none; font-weight:400; line-height:14px; text-align:normal; padding:0px; }

h3 { font-family:'cooper'; font-size:26px; line-height:24px; text-align:center; text-transform:lowercase; font-weight:400; letter-spacing:0px; margin-top:5px; color:{color:italic}; }



/*   ------   captions   ------   */



.tumblr_parent { margin:10px 10px 20px; padding: 0px 10px; border-left: 0px solid #ccc; font-size:7px; }

.tumblr_parent:after { content:''; display:block; width:100%; height:1px; margin:15px auto; background:{color:border}; }

.tumblr_parent:last-of-type:after { display:none; }

.tumblr_parent blockquote { margin-left:20px; padding-left:20px; border-left: 2px solid #ccc; }

.tumblr_avatar { margin:0px 6px 0px 0px; width:12px; vertical-align:middle; padding:2px; border-radius:50%; border:1px solid #ddd; background:black; }

a.tumblr_blog { border-bottom:2px solid {color:background}; font-weight:700; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:8px; letter-spacing:1px; padding:3px; border-radius:2px; }

.caption { padding:0px 10px 0px 10px; }



/*   ------   images/videos   ------   */



img { border:none; max-width:100%; height:auto; border-radius:2px; -webkit-filter:grayscale(50%); -moz-transition-duration:1s; -webkit-transition-duration:1s; -o-transition-duration:1s; }

img:hover { -webkit-filter:grayscale(0%); -moz-transition-duration:1s; -webkit-transition-duration:1s; -o-transition-duration:1s; }

resize { width: 300px; height:auto; }

#posts img { -webkit-filter:grayscale(50%); -moz-transition-duration:1s; -webkit-transition-duration:1s; -o-transition-duration:1s; }

.photoset {  width:100%; border-radius:2px; -webkit-filter:grayscale(50%); -moz-transition-duration:1s; -webkit-transition-duration:1s; -o-transition-duration:1s; }

#posts img:hover { -webkit-filter:grayscale(0%); -moz-transition-duration:1s; -webkit-transition-duration:1s; -o-transition-duration:1s; }

.photoset:hover { max-width:100%; -webkit-filter:grayscale(0%); -moz-transition-duration:1s; -webkit-transition-duration:1s; -o-transition-duration:1s; }



/*   ------   body   ------   */



#contain { background:{color:contain}; width:700px; height:600px; margin:auto; left:0px; right:0px; top:0px; bottom:0px; position:absolute; border-radius:2px; overflow:visible; z-index:1; background-image:url('{image:contain}'); background-blend-mode:soft-light; }

#entries { width:340px; height:680px; border-radius:2px; bottom:-40px; right:40px; font-size:10px; position:absolute; font-family:'ABeeZee', sans-serif; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto; letter-spacing:0px; }

#post { margin:auto; top:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px; left:0px; width:300px; background: {color:postbg}; padding:20px; position:relative; border-radius:2px; margin-bottom:30px; margin-top:0px; }

#post i,em { color:{color:italic}; }

#post strong { color:{color:bold};  text-shadow:0px 0px 2px {color:bold}; }



/*   ------   sidebar   ------   */


.sidebar { position:absolute; left:0px; bottom:0px; width:320px; height:600px; overflow:hidden; }

img {
    position: relative;
    left: 107px;
    top: 32px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
}
.image {
    position: absolute;
    left: 99px;
    top: 24px;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 8px solid c5c6cc;
    border: 8px dashed #c49683;
    animation-name: spinning-circle;
    animation-duration: 20s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    outline-color: #EA3556;

}

@-webkit-keyframes spinning-circle {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }

}



.title { position:absolute; top:170px; right:-30px; width:350px; height:auto; padding:10px; letter-spacing:-2px; font-size:40px; line-height:26px; text-align:center; color:#686868; font-family:'bambi'; font-weight:800; text-shadow:4px -3px #c49683; text-transform:lowercase; font-style:normal; z-index:1; -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #686868; -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); }




.navbar { position:absolute; top:234px; left:0px; overflow:visible; width:320px; height:5px; text-align:center; z-index:99999999999; }

ul.navig8 { position:absolute; overflow:visible; list-style-type:none; padding:0; width:320px; height:40px; top:8px; left:0px; z-index:999999999; text-transform:uppercase; text-align:center; }

ul.navig8 li { width:auto; display:inline; margin:5px; }

ul.navig8 li a { display:inline-block; color:{color:nav text}; letter-spacing:3px; font-size:7px; padding:3px; font-weight:600;  }

ul.navig8 li b { color:{color:bold}; }

.desc { position:absolute; width:210px; line-height:18px; height:226px; bottom:86px; left:50px; overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:visible; font-size:9px; padding:5px; color:{color:desc text}; text-transform:lowercase; font-family:'ABeeZee', sans-serif; letter-spacing:.5.5px; text-align:justify; z-index:9999; text-shadow:none; }

.desc:hover { opacity:1; }

.desc b, strong { color:{color:italic}; font-size:12px; font-weight:500; text-transform:lowercase; font-variant:none; font-family:'coco'; text-shadow:0px 0px 2px {color:italic}; }

.desc i, em { color:{color:italic}; text-shadow:none;  }

.desc a { color:{color:italic}; text-shadow:0px 0px 2px {color:italic}; }

.desc strong { font-size:16px; font-family:'cooper'; letter-spacing:1px; }



/*   ------   pagination   ------   */



#pagination { width:310px; position:absolute; height:14px; padding:5px; padding-top:3px; margin:auto; bottom:46px; left:0px; word-spacing:20px; text-align:center; color:{color:text}; z-index:999; }

#pagination a { padding:5px; padding-left:8px; color:{color:nav text}; font-weight:bold; letter-spacing:5px; font-size:7px; border-radius:2px; }
```

Comment: Can you produce a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happen for this code -

```
img {
    position: relative;
    left: 107px;
    top: 32px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
}
```

Replace it with this code -

```
.sidebar img {
    position: relative;
    left: 107px;
    top: 32px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
}
```